# Gitlab CI/CD downloading files in the test is completed by assigning the .crdownload format

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab, continuous-integration, mocha.js, cicd

Project structure [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGzDX.png). Initializing the driver in the basepage class and specifying the option to the google chrome browser using download.default_directory so that any downloaded files end up in our project

```
export class BasePage {
    public driver: WebDriver;
    constructor() {
      const PipeLineOptions = new chrome.Options();
      PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--disable-notifications');
      PipeLineOptions.addArguments('start-maximized');
      PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--log-level=DEBUG');
      PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--disable-gpu');
      PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--no-sandbox');
      PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--headless');
      PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage');
      PipeLineOptions.setUserPreferences({
        'download.default_directory': `${__dirname}/../downloads`,
      });
      this.driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(PipeLineOptions).build();
    }

    async createLocalDriver(): Promise<WebDriver> {
          this.driver = new Builder().withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome()).build();
          return this.driver
    }

    async createPipeLineDriver(): Promise<WebDriver> {
          const PipeLineOptions = new chrome.Options();
          PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--disable-notifications');
          PipeLineOptions.addArguments('start-maximized');
          PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--log-level=DEBUG');
          PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--disable-gpu');
          PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--no-sandbox');
          PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--headless');
          PipeLineOptions.addArguments('--disable-dev-shm-usage');
          PipeLineOptions.setUserPreferences({
              'download.default_directory': `${__dirname}/../downloads`,
          });
          this.driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').setChromeOptions(PipeLineOptions).build();
          return this.driver
      }
     async quitDriver() {
       await this.driver.quit();
     }
}
```

Code where the tests are located:

```
import {Constants} from "../utils/Constants";
import {allure} from "allure-mocha/runtime";
import {afterEach, describe, test} from "mocha";
import {MainPage} from "../pages/MainPage";

const mainPage = new MainPage();

describe("Start Test", async function () {

    before(async function () {
        await mainPage.quitDriver()
    });
    beforeEach(async function () {
        // await mainPage.createLocalDriver()
        await mainPage.createPipeLineDriver()
    });
    afterEach(async function () {
        let testCaseName: string | undefined = this.currentTest?.title;
        let testCaseStatus: "failed" | "passed" | "pending" | undefined = this.currentTest?.state;
        if (testCaseStatus === "failed") {
            console.log(`Test: ${testCaseName}, Status: Failed!`);
        } else if (testCaseStatus === "passed") {
            console.log(`Test: ${testCaseName}, Status: Passed!`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Test: ${testCaseName}, Status: Unknown!`);
        }
        await mainPage.quitDriver()
    });
    describe("Downloads file", async function() {
    
        test("first test", async function() {
            this.timeout(0);
            await mainPage.first_test();
        });
        test("second test", async function() {
            this.timeout(0);
            await mainPage.second_test();
        });
    });
});
```

The first test code should follow the link, download the file, and display the contents of the downloads folder that appears during the tests in the pipeline

```
    async first_test() {
        await this.driver.get("https://dwweb.ru/__a-data/__all_for_scripts/__rar/pro_dw_koments_1_3.rar");
        // await Utils.delay(120000); // 2 minutes
        // await Utils.delay(300000); // 5 minutes
        // await Utils.delay(600000); // 10 minutes

        fs.readdir(__dirname + "/../downloads", (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(files);
            }
        });

        await Utils.delay(Constants.timeout); // timeout 5 second
    }
```

The second test displays the contents of the downloads folder to check the file after passing 1 test:

```
    async second_test() {
        await Utils.delay(Constants.timeout);
        fs.readdir(__dirname + "/../downloads", (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(files);
            }
        });
        await Utils.delay(Constants.timeout);
    }
```

Contents of package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "selenium",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "module": "es6",
  "description": "Sample project which shows Typescript testing with Mocha, Chai, Selenium",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require ts-node/register 'src/__tests__/*.test.ts' --reporter allure-mocha",
    "copy_history": "cp -r allure-report/history allure-results",
    "generate_report": "allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.1",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^4.1.15",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.23.0",
    "allure-mocha": "^2.4.0",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "mocha-allure-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^3.10.111",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.11.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "uuid": "^7.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.5",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  }
}
```

YML file code for passing pipelines in Gitlab:

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  image: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
  allow_failure: true
  variables:
    DISPLAY: 99
  before_script:
    - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y npm
    - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y curl
    - curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | sudo bash -
    - sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
    - npm install
  script:
    - npm run test
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - allure-results
    expire_in: 2 days
```

Screenshot of running tests in the pipeline:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWPbL.png)
The main problem is the following: when going through pipelines, a file should be downloaded, but during the passage the file seems to be not completely downloaded or is at some stage at all and a file of the following format ends up in the downloads folder - export-tasks.pdf.crdownload(the same with xlsx, csv format). What options are there? solutions to this problem?

I tried to add a timeout after downloading the file in 2,5,10 minutes. Also an attempt to rename the file (unsuccessful).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.