# CI/CD downloading files in the test is completed by assigning the .crdownload format

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab, continuous-integration, mocha.js, gitlab-ci

The main problem is the following: when going through pipelines, a file should be downloaded, but during the passage the file seems to be not completely downloaded or is at some stage at all and a file of the following format ends up in the downloads folder - export-tasks.pdf.crdownload(the same with xlsx, csv format). What options are there? solutions to this problem?

I tried to add a timeout after downloading the file in 2,5,10 minutes. Also an attempt to rename the file (unsuccessful).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: .crdownload is the extension Chrome uses for a partial download.  (It starts out as .crdownload... when completed, Chrome will rename the file)

Comment: @pcalkins
Yes, I know this, but specifically in my case, when executing pipelines, the test itself which clicks on a button, then downloads and then in the folder (using the output of its contents) I see this file format, I tried to add timeouts so that the file would download and rename it didn't work.

Comment: before quitting the browser/driver, check to see if there are any .crdownload files.  If there are, wait as that means there's downloads in progress.

Comment: @pcalkins , Please read the question carefully and try to find a solution - I tried to add a timeout after downloading the file in 2,5,10 minutes. Also an attempt to rename the file (unsuccessful).

Comment: @pcalkins ,  Check out this question (it's mine, more detailed information is contained there). And let me know if you know the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77174028/gitlab-ci-cd-downloading-files-in-the-test-is-completed-by-assigning-the-crdown

Comment: renaming the file will get you nowhere.  You need to wait until the folder no longer contains files with the ".crdownload" extension before you quit the driver.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56777681/4744568